# jQuery - checkbox unselect does not fade back in

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a little piece of jQuery. On checking a checkbox, I want certain parts of the screen to fade out and when I check it again, for them to display. It's doing the fadeout part on checking the box but not the fade in. The piece of JQuery looks like:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#chkUnsubAll').change(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("checked")) {

                $('#HCV').fadeIn();
                $('#optIn').fadeIn();
                $('#Duopa').fadeIn();
                return;
            }
            else {
                $('#HCV').fadeOut();
                $('#optIn').fadeOut();
                $('#Duopa').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The relevant markup is:

```
  <div class="row">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UnsubscribeAll, new { id = "chkUnsubAll"})
        @Html.Label("Unsubscribe from ALL AbbVie communications")
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="optIn">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Optin Status:</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="HCV">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HCV)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HCV)
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1">Consumer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HCCEPhone)
                @Html.Label("HCCE - Phone")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HCCEMail)
                @Html.Label("HCCE - Mail")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HCCEEMail)
                @Html.Label("MCCE - Email")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HCCEInPerson)
                @Html.Label("MCCE - In Person")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1">HCP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ClinicalDataMail)
                @Html.Label("Clinical Data - Mail")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div clsss="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ClinicalDataEmail)
                @Html.Label("Clinical Data - Email")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr/>
    <div class="row" id="Duopa">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DUOPA)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DUOPA)
    </div>
```

First of all, the jQuery seems backward to me. I expected it, when checked to take the if path, not the else. Second, once those divs have been faded out, they don't fade back in when I uncheck the box. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it did not worked because checkbox checked property is being updated and not its attribute value.

Also you can use `.fadeToggle()` with true/false as an argument  to make show/hide decision:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chkUnsubAll').change(function() {
         $('#HCV,#optIn,#Duopa').fadeToggle(this.checked);
         return;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. I'll mark it as the answer shortly.

Comment: @user2471435: glad it helps :)

Comment: `fadeToggle() with true/false as an argument to make show/hide decision:`????????? , I think only `toggle()` will take boolean as an argument not in `fadeToggle()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan: yes....also you used the same method earlier and then changed it. isnt it?? most of the toggle method accepts boolean parameter to make show hide decision

Comment: @MilindAnantwar : check https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/waj6vpb2/1/ , I'm passing `true` as parameter but it's still toggling :).... Actually in your answer no need for that argument'.... It will only work with toggle.... https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/r9h1ruot/

Comment: @PranavCBalan: yes. but decision of toggling is strictly depends on checked state of checkbox. so this might break when initial condition have discrepancy. i.e. some of them are hidden in beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

1. `this.checked` to get checkbox is checked or not
2. You can use common selector by `,` separated as `'#HCV,#optIn,#Duopa'`

**CODE :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chkUnsubAll').change(function() {
      var sel = $('#HCV,#optIn,#Duopa');
      if(this.checked)
         sel.fadeIn();
      else
         sel.fadeOut();
   });
});
```